# GpyOpt ignores constraints. What is the correct way to specify them?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, bayesian, gpyopt

I want to run a constrained optimization in `GpyOpt`. Say, I want to minimize

[image]

where

[image]

s.t. at least one [image] is non-zero and, and not more than 3 can be equal to 1. So I specify constraints:

[image]

Based on the reference manual [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/GPyOpt/blob/devel/manual/GPyOpt_constrained_optimization.ipynb), it looks like we can specify constraints using `numpy` function. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184833/how-do-i-add-limiting-conditions-when-using-gpyopt) is suggested that we can specify constraints in the call to `BayesianOptimization`. So I express this in `GpyOpt` using the following code

```python
import numpy as np
import GPyOpt
from GPyOpt.methods import BayesianOptimization

seed = 6830
np.random.seed(seed)

def f(x):
    print(np.sum(x[:]), end=" ") # check if constraints are satisfied
    z = np.sum(x)
    return z**2

bounds = [{"name": "x", "type" : "discrete", 
           "domain" : (0, 1), "dimensionality": 10}]

constraints = [{'name' : 'more_than_0','constraint' : '-np.sum(x[:]) + 0.1'},
               {'name' : 'less_than_3','constraint' : 'np.sum(x[:]) - 3'}]

bopt = BayesianOptimization(f, domain=bounds, constraints=constraints)
bopt.run_optimization(max_iter=10)
```

However, it looks like `GpyOpt` is ignoring these constraints because I get the following output in the console:

```
6.0 1.0 5.0 7.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 2.0
```

which contains both values above 3 and a 0.

If I write out `np.sum(x[:])` explicitly as `x[:, 0] + x[:, 1] + ...` the behaviour does not change.

If I specify continuous domain, constraints are still violated.

What is the correct way to pass constraints, such that they are not ignored?

I am using `GpyOpt` version 1.2.1.

UPDATE:
`np.sum(x, 1)` instead of `np.sum(x[:])` does not solve the issue.

I am using Python 3.6.3 with numpy 1.14.2 and GPyOpt 1.2.1 installed through pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you are summing up the x's right. The constraint expression is supposed to work over whole X and output an array of values per data point, which are then each checked against the constraint.

When I change the summing in both expressions to:

```
np.sum(x, axis=1)
```

and leave your code otherwise completely intact, the output is:

```
1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1
```

No violations.

Comment: What versions of Python/GpyOpt/numpy are you using? This does not solve issue for me, but since you cannot reproduce it, I expect it can be related to different versions.

Comment: @NickTo, Python 3.6, GPyOpt 1.2.1, Numpy 1.13

Comment: Installing the development version from Github **and** changing the way I do summation fixed the problem.